# C++ get UTC time with milliseconds

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I need to get UTC time with milliseconds, I tried use it:

```
std::string getCurrentUTC()
{
    namespace bg = boost::gregorian;
    static char const* const fmt = "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S";
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new bg::date_facet(fmt)));
    ss << bg::day_clock::universal_day();
    return ss.str();
}
```

But it prints the following:

```
2020-Jun-29 00:00:00
```

I need the following format:

```
2020-Jun-29 00:00:00.000
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `static char const* const fmt = "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S.000";`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Or `"%Y-%b-%d 00:00:00.000"`, same result.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the UTC time with millisecond as follow:

```
struct timeb timebStruct;
ftime(&timebStruct);
struct tm               *tmStruct = new tm();
gmtime_r(&timebStruct.time, tmStruct);
std::cout <<  tmStruct->tm_hour
                            << tmStruct->tm_min <<  tmStruct->tm_sec <<  
timebStruct.millitm << std::endl
```

Comment: There is a memory leak in `tmStruct`.

Answer (score 1):

Using this [free, open-source, header-only preview of C++20 `<chrono>`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) you can write:

```
#include "date/date.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string
getCurrentUTC()
{
    namespace ch = std::chrono;
    using date::operator<<;
    static char const* const fmt = "%Y-%b-%d %T";
    std::ostringstream ss;
    auto tp = ch::time_point_cast<ch::milliseconds>(ch::system_clock::now());
    ss << date::format(fmt, tp);
    return ss.str();
}
```

This works in C++11/14/17.  For me it just output:

```
2020-Jun-29 13:42:21.946
```

which is the current time UTC to millisecond precision.

When C++20 `<chrono>` ships, this will port to it by:

- Remove `#include "date/date.h"`.
- Remove `using date::operator<<;`
- Add `#include <format>`
- Change `date::format` to `std::format`
- Change `"%Y-%b-%d %T"` to `"{:%Y-%b-%d %T}"`.